# Mysql not starting after upgrading debian squeeze to wheezy

Tags: mysql, debian

I recently bought a VPS box with Debian Squeeze pre-installed as the OS. I upgraded to Debian Wheezy and most things work fine (e.g. apache).

The problem I'm having relates to MySQL - which is just not starting since the upgrade to wheezy. I have researched this and tried many solutions along the lines of uninstalling and re-installing MySQL completely and yet i get the same fail message when the MySQL process attempts to start up.

Seems to be a dependency problem - but I don't understand what it means!

I have tried several solutions including some from this forum including:

- [How to reinstall broken mysql package](https://serverfault.com/questions/526693/how-to-reinstall-broken-mysql-package)
- [Failed mysql upgrade to 5.5 on debian wheezy](https://serverfault.com/questions/509410/failed-mysql-upgrade-to-5-5-on-debian-wheezy)

And these have still not resolved the issue.

The full trace of messages when I do a clean install is below - would appreciate any comments/help as am really stuck on this! Thanks.

```
root@vps:~# apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
libterm-readkey-perl tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 mysql-client mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4598 kB of archives.
After this operation, 71.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblzma5:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libavahi-common-data:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 29267 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-common (from .../mysql-common_5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18:i386.
Unpacking libmysqlclient18:i386 (from .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (from .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.021-1+b1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.5.
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (from .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblzma5:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libavahi-common-data:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 29365 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
Unpacking mysql-client (from .../mysql-client_5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Unpacking mysql-server (from .../mysql-server_5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18:i386 (5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.021-1+b1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1) ...
Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up mysql-client (5.5.35+dfsg-0+wheezy1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Check MySQL's log files to find the problem.

Comment: @Michael Hampton weirdly enough there are no errors logged. The fix for me was to set the default storage engine to MyISAM in my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM was the default storage engine for the MySQL relational database management system versions prior to 5.5  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM

Wheezy deprecates the use of MyISAM with MySQL 5.5.

Simply add:

`default-storage-engine=myisam`

..under the `[mysqld]` section in the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

I recently ran into this when doing an upgrade from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy. After the upgrade MySQL just failed to start.

The symptoms I got were a bit similar to what is posted here:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=682232

However, the proposed solution of

```
rm /var/lib/mysql/ib*
```

..did not work for me.

To make things more interesting, there were no errors written to the mysql log files. They were there, but just 0 bytes. Btw, the `/var/log/mysql` directory was empty.

```
wordpress:~#  l -dg /var/log/mysql*
drwxr-s--- 2 adm 4.0K Jun 10  2010 /var/log/mysql
-rw-r----- 1 adm    0 Oct  9 15:06 /var/log/mysql.err
-rw-r----- 1 adm    0 Oct  9 15:06 /var/log/mysql.log
```

I then ran the `mysqld` command from the command line. This finally produced some helpful information:

```
wordpress:~# mysqld
141009 15:39:50 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
141009 15:39:50 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
141009 15:39:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
141009 15:39:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
141009 15:39:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
141009 15:39:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
141009 15:39:50 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
141009 15:39:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(135987200 bytes) failed; errno 12
141009 15:39:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
141009 15:39:50 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
141009 15:39:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
141009 15:39:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
141009 15:39:50 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
141009 15:39:50 [ERROR] Aborting

141009 15:39:50 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Apparently, InnoDB was not supported. This is fine for me as I have been using `MyISAM` in the past on this server.

A quick search for some of these errors pointed to a link (also on ServerFault) with the anser in one of the comments:

[Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB | MySQL Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/379714/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb-mysql-ubuntu)

The key is to specify the default storage engine as per Andy Mikhaylenko's answer.

Apparently the answer also speaks of adding `skip-innodb` but that wasn't a requirement on my system to make MySQL start up again.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, I got the error

> 160307 21:49:22 [ERROR] mysqld: unknown option '--skip-bdb'

so had to comment out the option

```
skip-bdb
```

as this is obviously not known any more to mysqld 5.5. Probably left over from quite an old version of mysql, as this box has started out with Debian sarge.